# MFMailComposeViewController navigationBar custom background color

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios9

I'm using MFMailComposeViewController and I'd like to change background color so it matches the one I have across the app. I've tried several things, but nothing worked(at least not on iOS 9).

```
let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
...

mailVC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()] // this works
mailVC.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // this works
mailVC.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()  // this doesn't work
mailVC.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()  // this doesn't work
```

Background color stays default gray.

Comment: You've got some Objective C in there

Comment: Never mind, I'm dumb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by setting color of navigationbar before initializing `MFMailComposeViewController` like this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()

let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
```

Comment: This does not work. This sets the navigation bar color for the entire app.

Comment: @RickS it does work. You have to set the color to the one you prefer back after dismissing MFMailComposeViewController()